# How to get ArrayList value from a Object ArrayList in java?

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist, arrayobject

I have an `ArrayList` of `Object`s. I have added some objects and an `ArrayList` of `String`s to this `ArrayList`. I can easily get the objects value from it. Now my question is how can I get the whole `ArrayList` of `String`s from it?

Code snippet :

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int number;

    public Learn(String name, int number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number= number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

Now I have defined object List

```
List<Object> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now it's time to add some ***Person*** in itemsList

```
public void addPerson(){
    itemsList.add(new Person("Alex", 0000062846));
    itemsList.add(new Person("Jack", 0000131332));
    itemsList.add(new Person("Anjela", 0000053715));
    itemsList.add(new Person("Brian", 0000085015));
}
```

Now, I will add a ***String List*** at the index of 2

```
public void addList(){
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
    strList.add("Hello");
    strList.add("How");
    strList.add("are");
    strList.add("you?");

    itemsList.add(2, strList);
}
```

Alright, it's time to get the values from `itemsList`

```
Person person = (Person) itemsList.get(0);
System.out.println(person.getName);  // Alex
```

Now my question is : How can I get `strList` from `itemsList`?

Comment: Why did you make array list like this?

Comment: I Have a heterogeneous recyclerView in android. I want to pass a whole arrayList to this recyclerView which can be used to show a viewPager as a item

Comment: `List<String> strList = (List<String>) items.getList(...)` but really, why?

Comment: As you are creating such different list, while retrieving you have to write `if` conditions to check the instance of the item at `index`. This is not good design though. `instanceof` is a costly operation too.

Comment: This is a messy approach.

Comment: @Uma Yeah, I also use instance of to check the object

Comment: This approach is such a mess. Why not make an ArrayList of type Interface which holds your classes. Then make each class implement that interface. Add a function to the interface which returns an identifier

Comment: @ZUNJAE thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `instanceof` for that, by using `instanceof` find the `Object` type in `List<Object>`

```
for(Object obj : itemsList) {

    if(obj instanceof List) {    //if it is List type then type cast it

          List<String> str = (List<String>) obj;
          for(String s : str) {

             System.out.println(s);

                  }
          }
    }
```

But according to the discussion in comments, suppose if you have `List<String>` and `List<Integers>` in `List<Object> itemsList` then while at the time of type casting exception will be thrown, because in runtime `List<String>` and `List<Integers>` both are treated as `List

```
List<String> str = (List<String>) obj;    //exception thrown at this line
```

take a look at [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)
, so use generic lists for each type instead of `List to add different types

Comment: What happens if i decide to add another `List<Integer>` to `items` for later use, just to think one step further, to me this whole design approach looks very error prone.

Comment: It will throw an exception , to avoid that jdk people introduced generic concept @Glains

Comment: The point i want to make is, while this does indeed solve the problem, it is error prone for the future if other properties are added to the list. This note could be added to the answer.

Comment: @Glains the question is error prone to begin with. *That* should be added to the answer.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca That is true, but you can still give a good answer, even to a bad question.